# How to process each 'block' of text separately

Tags: python-3.x

Hoping you can help.

I have a file something like the below. There are lots of lines of text associated with an entry. each entry is separated by ***********

I have written some code that loops through each line, checks some criteria and then writes the output to a csv. However, I don't know how to do that for the whole section, rather than per line.

I kind of want WHILE line <> ***** loop through the lines. But I need to do that for each section in the document.

Would anyone be able to help please?

**My attempt:**
Split lines doesnt seem to work

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

output = "Desktop/data.csv"
f = open("Desktop/mpe.txt", "r")


lines = f.readlines().splitlines('*************************************************')
print(lines)
for line in lines:
    if 'SEND_HTTP' in line:
        date = line[:10]
        if 'FAILURE' in line:
            status = 'Failure'
        else:
            status = 'Success'
        if 'HTTPMessageResponse' in line:
            response = line

with open(output, "a") as fp:
     wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
     wr.writerow([date, status, response])
```

**The file:**

```
   line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    *************************************************

    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    line of text
    *************************************************
```

Comment: Could you please fix your proposed code to a state it actually runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first separates entry with [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split) method

```
f = open("Desktop/mpe.txt", "r")
sections = f.read().split("*************************************************\n")
for section in sections:
    for line in section.split("\n"):
        # your code here
```

Comment: If the number of asterisks isn't guaranteed you could use a regex, e.g: `sections = re.compile("^\*+$", re.MULTILINE).split(f.read())`

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through your example file, splitting each 'section' as denoted by 50 asterisk (`*`) characters

```
fileHandle = open(r"Desktop/mpe.txt", "r")
splitItems = fileHandle.read().split("*"*49)
for index, item in enumerate(splitItems):
    if(item == ""):
        continue
    print("[{}] {}".format(index, item))
```

You can remove the print statement and do what you need with the results. However, this form of parsing is not great as if the file doesn't have exactly 50 asterisks, this will break.

The `if` check skips any entries that are empty, which you will get if your example is accurate to the real data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a function get_sections which will return generator yielding one section at a time. This way you don't have to load the whole file in memory.

```py
def get_sections():
    with open("Desktop/mpe.txt") as f:
        section=[]
        for line in f:
            if("***********" not in line):
                section.append(line)
            else:
                yield section
                section=[]

for section in get_sections():
    print("new section")
    for line in section:
        print(line)
        ## do your processing here
```